# Can I grant permission on files on my AS3 bucket via HTTP request parameters?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket with files in it in **AS3**. I have access to the **PHP API** and a server that can send requests to Amazon on command.

What I want to do is grant access to a file in my bucket using an `HTTP GET/POST` request. From what I understand using this function:

```
get_object_url ( $bucket, $filename, $preauth, $opt )
```

I can make the file publicly accessible for the `$preauth` amount of time at a given URL. I don't want to do that, I want the file to be privately available at a URL with required **POST** or **GET** credentials (deciding who can access the file would be based on a database containing application 'users' and their permissions). I understand the security implications of passing any kind of credentials over **GET** or **POST** on a **non-HTTPS** connection.

Is this possible? I could just download the file from **AS3** to my server for the extent of the transaction then do all the controls on my own box, but that's an expensive solution (two file downloads instead of one, when my server shouldn't have had to do a download at all) to a seemingly easy problem.

Comment: Doesn't the PHP API you use have a method to set Acess Control Policy for an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short answer is no.**

You could look at [Amazons IAM](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) for some more ways to secure the content especially in conjunction with [Cloudfront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) but essentially there is no way to provide access to content by passing along a username and password.

Of course, if you are already authenticating users on your site, then you can only supply the signed url to those users. The url only has to be valid at the time the user initiates the download and not for the entire duration of the download.

Also, if you intend to use your server as a proxy between S3 and the user you'll be removing a lot of the benefits of using S3 in the first place. But you could use EC2 as the server to remove the extra cost you mentioned - transfers between S3 and EC2 are free.